# Jquery animation not working on angular directive in $watch

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, fadein

```
scope.$watch('datat', function(newIsOpenVal, oldIsOpenVal) {
   $("#externald-not-the-element").fadeOut( 1000, function() {
     $("#externald-not-the-element").remove();
   });
)};
```

Inside the directive I can't use jQuery while it's working in the console.
I've installed `ng-animate` and the `fadeOut` animation is not working  but `.css()` works.

How can I fix it ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: try using `angular.element("#externald-not-the-element")` instead of `$("#externald-not-the-element")`

Comment: As long as you have jQuery, this should work just fine. Also, you don't need `ng-animate` for this since you are using jQuery: http://plnkr.co/edit/k4NYEG3vDhvFlqGALD90?p=preview

Comment: @tasseKAT not working in the directive

Comment: You need to be more specific. Can you show the directive and HTML?

Comment: ng-animate is not responsible for `.fadeOut`, that is a [`jQuery` function](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/), make sure you have jQuery installed, as angular only comes with jQLite (a cut down version of jQuery) by default which does not contain animation functions